# Submit form in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

In my Rails view, I have an HTML form

```
<form name="input">
Username: <input type="text" name="user"> <br/>
<input type="button" id="submit_form" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When the submit button is clicked, I want to use JQuery to call the controller `download`, and also pass along the `user` parameter. (In `routes.rb` I specify `match "download" => "Posts#download"`)

How should I use JQuery to do this?

```
$("#submit_form").click(function() {
  // what should I put here?
});
```

Comment: Also, you should add an id to the form to be able to select it easier through jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $("#submit_form").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault(); 

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        term = $form.find( 'input[name="user"]' ).val(),

    /* Send the data using post and fire some callback */
    $.post( "/download", { s: term },
      function( data ) {
       //some callback
      }
    );
  });
```

Source: Modified [example](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) from jQuery docs

Comment: This is pretty much spot on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit_form").click(function() {
  // what should I put here?
  $('form[name="input"]').submit();
});
```

Or you can just set type="submit" to your input with id="submit_form" and don't set any handlers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Rails developer but can't you put the route in the forms action and then use submit, as follows:

```
<form name="input" action="/Download">

$("#submit_form").click(function() {
  $("#input").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides a .submit() http://api.jquery.com/submit/

You don't need to bind to the click method of the input button as that submit button already knows to submit the form.

What you are looking for is

```
$("form[name='input']").submit(function(){
  //do something before function gets submitted
});
```

Inside that function you'll want an ajax call to your server and use preventDefault to cancel the original submit of the form.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to submit the form through jQuery instead of the normal post process. I'd suggest using [jQuery's form submit function](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit)

Basically you'll be looking for something like:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: "controller/action",
    type: "POST",
    data: data
    // plus anyother options you are wanting
  }).done(function() { 
    // a success function
  });
  return false;
  });
```

Hope that helps.